# Combining Deterministic and Random Unbiased Estimators

Tags: bayesian, estimation, monte-carlo, approximation

I am trying to compute an expectation $E[f(X;\theta,n)]$ where $\theta$ and $n$ are known parameters. I have an easy-to-compute deterministic function $\tilde{f}(\theta,n)$ that provides an approximation to $E[f(X;\theta,n)]$ that gets better as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (but always underestimates the true value). I can also sample directly from $f(X;\theta,n)$ and compute the Monte Carlo estimate $\hat{f}$, which is unbiased but can have a large variance for some $\theta$ and $n$.

I am wondering if there are similar problems that might yield methods for estimating $E[f(X;\theta,n)]$ which combine these two estimates. Since we know $\tilde{f}(\theta,n)\rightarrow E[f(X;\theta,n)]$ as $n$ increases, it seems like it might also be possible to compute the estimators for a range of values of $n$ and use the asymptotic behavior to somehow constrain the fitted values.

The only approach I can think of is to use a Bayesian estimate of $E[f(X;\theta,n)]$ by taking the sample mean of the Monte Carlo samples and incorporating a prior having mean $\tilde{f}$. This seems like an OK start, but at the very least I'd like to be able to incorporate the knowledge that $E[f]>\tilde{f}$. It also seems quite likely that a more sophisticated approach exists for a similar problem, but I'm just not sure where to start in searching the literature.

Comment: I suggest a prior that is supported only on $E[f]>\tilde{f}$, since this is a better summary of your prior information. [Pareto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) with shape parameter increasing in $n$ would be a reasonable place to start. Even better estimates could be computed if you have an upper bound on $E[f]$. If you give more detail about the distribution of $X$ and function $f$, I expect more informative answers would be possible.